# Loading base64 encoded pdf into chrome iframe with pdf open parameters

Tags: html

The examples I've seen assign an iframe's src from a local file with open parameters.

I'm trying to open a base64 encoded pdf with toolbar=0:

```
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = getFileAsUri(viewModel.source) + `#toolbar=0`;
```

If I leave off the `#toolbar=0` the pdf is displayed, when the parameter is present, chrome doesn't load the pdf:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Can a pdf be loaded using base64 and open paramters?

also tried:

```
const pdf = getFileAsUri(viewModel.source); //base64
const blob = new Blob([pdf], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = url + `#toolbar=0`;
```

error in the console:
'Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf'